# fast minimum distance between two low dimensional circulant matrices

Tags: matrices

i'd like to calculate the minimal distance between two circulant matrices. the thing is, they are rather small - thats why i do not know if its computationally less expensive to chose the brute force approach, as i've done so far.

This is what i'd like to do:
A,B are 4x4 Circulant Matrix, such as:

```
A = {
1,2,3.0,4;
4,1,2,3.0;
3.0,4,1,2;
2,3.0,4,1}

B = {
3.4,4,1,2;
2,3.4,4,1;
1,2,3.4,4;
4,1,2,3.4}
```

The minimal squared distance of the example is `1.6`. Right now i calculate this by doing a 4x1 distance matrix between the first row of B and all the rows of A.
Since I only need a distance measure and not necessarily the euclidean distance, i thought i could apply some ideas from Fourier Transformations. But i think this would be computational overkill for only 4 combinations. I am sure there has to be some simple method, but I cannot find it/think of it. Does anyone of you have an idea of a better strategy to compare A and B?

**SPECIFICALLY**

A vector $c_k$ in ${\rm I\!R}^n$ specifies the $n\times n$ circulant Matrix $C_k$. While $k \in {\rm I\!N} \cap k \geq 0 \cap k<K$ with our current data $ K<10^6$. And due to the nature of the data $n=4$. 
At the moment I brutally calculate for any combination of $k_1$ and $k_2$ the $n$ dimensional vector $d$ by $d_{(j)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (C_{k_2,j,i}-C_{k_1,1,i})^2$. Thus, the minimal squared distance $D$ I am looking for is $\min_{j=1}^n(d_j) $.

Well, I know my approach works - and as it is implemented so far (CUDA) it computes quite fast too. But now I wonder if there is a smarter way to calculate **some** distance between two circular matrices. Most probably, if $n>> $ it could be helpful to use Fourier Transformation. But with the low dimensionality of the data, this approach is computationally too expensive (at least I think so).

Answer (score 0):

for those who are interested: i had a workshop today with Richard M Karp and got the chance to discuss this problem with him. sadly, the described and implemented version is the fastest strategy. all other approaches are computationally much more expensive. therefore i have my answer, although i've hoped to be wrong.